# Android Studio: "SDK installation does not have the "Extras > Android Support Repository" installed" BUT IT HAS BEEN INSTALLED

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I created Android Project but then I immediately get information that there have been errors.

```
Warning:(22, 12) Dependency on a support library, but the SDK installation does not have the "Extras > Android Support Repository" installed. Open the SDK manager and install it.
```

But I installed it, it was installed at the installation of Android Studio. I created another project and it happen again.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68834 and will be fixed in 0.5.9. In the meantime you can ignore the warning.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was a very silly error and I spent the last two days trying to get around this. The path to the SDK in `local.properties` file was not properly escaped.

Change this:

```
# Location of the android SDK
sdk.dir=C:/Android/sdk
```

to this:

```
# Location of the android SDK
sdk.dir=C\:/Android/sdk
```

Refresh the gradle again.

Comment: Thanks a million. Stuff like this that makes me hate Android development.

Comment: @CorneBeukes yeah :D But there's always answers to those problems. Like this one.

Answer (score 0):

When you download Android Studio you have 0.5.2 version,There is a solution is to downgrade exactly to 0.5.4 
and download from here : [Android Studio 0.5.4](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/0-5-4)

after download the file just drag and drop in the place where you installed Android studio 0.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this bug appears to have resurfaced since it was last fixed. I have filed a new bug report to track it:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37592307

Please "star" the bug report if it's affecting you.